# View for 404 error page

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I have one controller which detects if there is content available. If not, I want the user to get an error page. Currently I use:

```
if(!$translation) {
    App::abort(404);
}
```

I don't know how to style the 404 error page. Where is the view file for that, or how else should I proceed?

Comment: You simply ignored documentation and just went to cry for help on SO. Always-always consult documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Customize the error page for 404 HTTP status codes, create a 
>   `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. This file will be served on
>   all 404 errors generated by your application. The views within this
>   directory should be named to match the HTTP status code they
>   correspond to. The HttpException instance raised by the abort function
>   will be passed to the view as an $exception variable.

See [Laravel Documentation on Custom Http Error Pages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Comment: Thanks, man. I have already that file, but i was searching it in another folder :)

Comment: Glad to see, that it helped you!